# reformat json in desired format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

```
{
    "EUR": {
        "Description": "",
        "Bid": "1.1222",
        "Region": "",
        "Bid1": "1.1283",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "FeedSource": "1",
        "Ask": "1.1226",
        "ProviderName": "TEST 1",
        "Low": "1.1195",
        "LastModified": "2014-05-20T08:11:13",
        "CreatedBy": "10000",
        "OpenBid": "1.12",
        "QuotedCurrencyCode": "USD"
    },
    "PHP": {
        "Description": "",
        "Bid": "46.75",
        "Region": "",
        "Bid1": "4.59",
        "CurrencyCode": "PHP",
        "FeedSource": "1",
        "Ask": "46.755",
        "ProviderName": "Test2",
        "Low": "4.715",
        "LastModified": "2016-05-20T07:54:32",
        "CreatedBy": "10000",
        "QuotedCurrencyCode": "USD"
    }
}
```

Need to reformat this json in below format,

```
{ CurrencyCode: "EUR", LastModified: "10/02/2012", ProviderName: "Test1", Bid: "1.2", Bid1: "1.19", Bid2: "1.2", Ask: "2CloseBid: "32", CloseAsk: "35" },
              { CurrencyCode: "PHP", LastModified: "10/02/2012", ProviderName: "Test2", Other fields... }]
```

I want to do this conversion in javascript.
Tried with stringify and parse but it doesn't give desired output.
Please suggest

Comment: You use jqgrid tag for the question. Do you want to use the data as input for jqGrid? Which `datatype` you use? If you use `datatype: "json"`, then it's important to know whether you use `loadonce: true` or not. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?

Comment: What is your desired data type is it object or array of object?

Comment: $("#grid").empty().jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'jsonstring',
                    datastr: gridJson,loadOnce :true

Comment: jquery.jqGrid from triand.com
 4.4.4  - jQuery Grid

Following this code from,
http://shanemccall.blogspot.in/2012/02/json-and-jqgrid-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for-in` loop & iterate over each `key`

```
let input = {
    "EUR": {
        "Description": "",
        "Bid": "1.1222",
        "Region": "",
        "Bid1": "1.1283",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "FeedSource": "1",
        "Ask": "1.1226",
        "ProviderName": "TEST 1",
        "Low": "1.1195",
        "LastModified": "2014-05-20T08:11:13",
        "CreatedBy": "10000",
        "OpenBid": "1.12",
        "QuotedCurrencyCode": "USD"
    },
    "PHP": {
        "Description": "",
        "Bid": "46.75",
        "Region": "",
        "Bid1": "4.59",
        "CurrencyCode": "PHP",
        "FeedSource": "1",
        "Ask": "46.755",
        "ProviderName": "Test2",
        "Low": "4.715",
        "LastModified": "2016-05-20T07:54:32",
        "CreatedBy": "10000",
        "QuotedCurrencyCode": "USD"
    }
}

var output = [];
for(let key in input){
  output.push(input[key])
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: It returns,["{", """, "E", "U", "R", """, ":", "{", """, "D", "e", "s", "c", "r", "i", "p", "t", "i", "o", "n", """, ":", """, """, ",", """, "B", "i", "d", """, ":", """, "1", ".", "1", "2", "0", "1", """, ",", """, "R", "e", "g", "i", "o", "n", """, ":", """, """, ",", """, "B", "i", "d", "1", """, ":", """, "1", ".", "1", "2", "1", "5", """, ",", """, "C", "u", "r", "r", "e", "n", "c", "y", "C", "o", "d", "e", """, ":", """, "E", "U", "R", """, ",", """, "F", "e", "e", "d", "S", "o", "u", "r", "c", "e"…]

Comment: Yes @JagsSparrow, I will create a plunker for the same. Thanks

Comment: Sure, Let me know the link.

Comment: Hi pls see the plunker here,
https://plnkr.co/edit/sxehhpCCVDpqZ5zBKFq2?p=preview

If I pass the gridJson to jqGrid, it is formed as expected, but I can't bind the var input to the jqGrid, it displays nothing in grid. Please check. Thanks

Comment: JagsSparrow it works in the plunker but somehow not working in my environment. I mean if I hard code the value for input, it works in my environment also. But not with the valu I am receiving from function.

  myHub.on("getValues", function (value) {
                debugger;
                //var data = JSON.parse(value);
                //var gridJson1 = JSON.stringify(value);

                let input = value;  //setting input to value doen't work, but if I copy the data from value and pass it directly to input, it wotrks, can you tell me whats going wrong here